# Making a PHP class more modular

Tags: php, class, frameworks, modular

I'm trying to make a modular framework. I make a lot of websites and want to reuse a lot of code. Now I do that by making normal functions in separate php files that I include. For example I put all database functions in database.php al login code in login.php and all some string formatting functions in core.php

The core.php functionality is used in pretty much every project I do, some have login functionality and some use a database and some use all.

So now I have something like this:

```
<?php
   require_once('core.php');
   require_once('database.php');
   require_once('login.php');

   dbConnect('user','pw');
   loginShow();
   echo stringFunction('blabla');
?>
```

Now I wanna do it a bit nicer and use Objects and Classes.
So I would have a Core class, database class and login class but the login class might also need database and core functions but not always.

A system where I have:

myframework.php:

```
class myFramework {
}
```

database.php:

```
class database extends myFramework {
}
```

login.php:

```
class login extends myFramework {
}
```

index.php:

```
include myframework.php
include login.php
include database.php
$site=new myFramework;
```

This wouldn't work since login functions aren't in myFramework but in Login class. But $site=new Login wouldn't work either since database function aren't in Login.

What I want is a class then I can really can expand with multiple included and only include the code I actually need for that project.
So far I've not been able to find a good solution so I hope asking for some advice here helps.

Comment: If you really want to use a framework i would suggest getting one that is already built. Building your own can be complicated and can end up being insecure if you are not familiar with what needs to be done. Either way I would go search Google for an existing one, or go read up on design patterns and look at tutorial on how to do it. There are many frameworks out there, if you want something small I would suggest laravel, fuelphp, phpixie and many many others

Comment: @mic is right. Don't invent a bicycle. But if you want, you can always look at source code of any existing framework.

Comment: The point is I already have the code working in functions so the framework is already there but I want to clean up the code and do it 'better'. But now I'm thinking that using Classes/Namespaces isn't really needed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should use namespaces rather then classes for this purpose.

Comment: Using namespaces and classes are not the things that exclude each other, so OP should use them both as they are for different purposes.